# Garmin Connect login php

Tags: php, authentication, curl

Attempting to authenticate to garmin connect using their new SSO method, but I keep getting stuck. I've found what I believe to be a working method in python here:

https://github.com/cpfair/tapiriik/commit/1604a1c791def072a48f3165dd61d5136f3610ce

My code so far is:

```
$url = "https://sso.garmin.com/sso/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&webhost=olaxpw-connect04.garmin.com&source=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fen-US%2Fsignin&redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&redirectAfterAccountCreationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&gauthHost=https%3A%2F%2Fsso.garmin.com%2Fsso&locale=en_US&id=gauth-widget&cssUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.garmincdn.com%2Fcom.garmin.connect%2Fui%2Fcss%2Fgauth-custom-v1.0-min.css&clientId=GarminConnect&rememberMeShown=true&rememberMeChecked=false&createAccountShown=true&openCreateAccount=false&usernameShown=true&displayNameShown=false&consumeServiceTicket=false&initialFocus=true&embedWidget=false";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
//echo $page;
   $username = '********';
$password = '************';

preg_match("/flowExecutionKey:\s\[(.*)-->/",$page,$m);
$flow = trim(str_replace(']','',$m[1]));
$ch = curl_init('https://sso.garmin.com/sso/login?service=http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login&clientID=GarminConnect&consumeServiceTicket=false');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
$query = http_build_query(array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,'embed'=>'true','_eventID'=>'submit','lt'=>$flow));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($url, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($http_status);
var_dump($output);
```

I am able to get the flow execution key without issue, but when I post it along with the required fields I get no output at all..

Comment: You never set `CURLOPT_POST`, which means you're doing a GET. Plus, you  set one url in curl_init, then replace it with $url on the very next line, and both urls are different.

Answer (score 1):

First try removing this line from code and run again. You are setting the previous url again here. So erase it.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
```

**If still doesn't work: then...**

You are browsing the login page with `$page = file_get_contents($url);` so any cookie from the site during this call is not stored in your `$cookie_file`.

So instead of calling that `file_get_contents` function, fetch the html using curl also with the same cookie file.

```
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$page= curl_exec($login);
curl_close($login);
```

If still doesn't work, then add this line with your second curl call.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

Finally use `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);` to see yourself for debugging what is curl doing.